# SuiteScript Unable to query for Inventory Number Bin record or BIN number

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am working with Lot Numbered Inventory, I have to get the "Inventory Numbered Bin" record or the very Least the BIN number. I have the "Inventory Number" record. I looked at the records browser for "Inventory Numbered BIN" and it says it is "join only" but I can't figure out what I join on as the available join field is only "user". I would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a reason I can't seem to find anywhere, the Inventory Number record does not directly join to the Inventory Number Bin record. However, the Inventory Number Bin record serves as the intermediary between the Inventory Number and Bin records.

If you look at the Inventory Number Bin record, you will find the "inventorynumber" and "binnumber" columns. These can be used in a search to get records without a direct join.

```
require(['N/search', 'N/record'], function(search, record) {
  // Load an inventory number record
  var inventoryNumber = record.load({ type: 'inventorynumber', id: 1234 });
  // Get the inventory number field
  var inventoryNumberId = inventoryNumber.getValue('inventorynumber');

  search.create({
    type: 'inventorynumberbin',
    filters: ['inventorynumber', 'is', inventoryNumberId],
    columns: ['binnumber']
  }).run()
    .each(function(result) {
      // Log the bin numbers related to the inventory number
      log.debug(result.getValue('binnumber'));
      return true;
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks, I was going out of my mind with this as it said "join only" so I thought I had to get to it "through" another record not just using a filter. They also have a saved search "type" that joins them but you can't call it from code, it states that it can't determine type. That's awesome, thanks very much, life saver.